# Bootstrap show many move one carousel modification

Tags: javascript, jquery, circular-list, twitter-bootstrap

I've been steadily improving a show many move one carousel sample that I found a few weeks ago. I want to post my improvements for others to use but don't want to spread bad code. I'm not an expert in JavaScript but I always like to produce clean code.

[Working demo](http://codepen.io/rtpHarry/pen/YPBydd)

```
(function(){
  $('.carousel-showmanymoveone .item').each(function(){
    var itemToClone = $(this);

    for (var i=1;i<4;i++) {
      itemToClone = itemToClone.next();

      // wrap around if at end of item collection
      if (!itemToClone.length) {
        itemToClone = $(this).siblings(':first');
      }

      // grab item, clone, add marker class, add to collection
      itemToClone.children(':first-child').clone()
        .addClass("cloneditem-"+(i))
        .appendTo($(this));
    }
  });
}());
```

#### Thoughts

I've done all the improvements I can think of but:

- I'm wondering about seeing `$(this)` appear twice.
- Are the siblings, children, :first-child, :first usages the best options?
- Any other improvements or best practices I've missed?

Is there something I could do better?

Comment: I'm satisfied [`siblings` is the best option](http://jsperf.com/jquery-siblings-vs-parent-find-vs-find)

Comment: Looks pretty clean for me. 
the only improvement that I will make , will be extract in a varible, after `.clone()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks for looking at this. I have concluded that I am happy with the code.

To incorporate the valid suggest by @vmariano, I have split this off into its own variable. This does make sense from a best-practices viewpoint as once I clone the item it is no longer `itemToClone` it is a `clonedItem`.

Final code:

```
(function(){
  $('.carousel-showmanymoveone .item').each(function(){
    var itemToClone = $(this);

    for (var i=1;i<4;i++) {
      itemToClone = itemToClone.next();

      // wrap around if at end of item collection
      if (!itemToClone.length) {
        itemToClone = $(this).siblings(':first');
      }

      // grab item, clone, add marker class, add to collection
      var clonedItem = itemToClone.children(':first-child').clone();
      clonedItem.addClass("cloneditem-"+(i))
         .appendTo($(this));
    }
  });
}());
```